# Can, if so how, do you send Private message on Askubuntu

Tags: support

If I'm trying to use a particular program, tried using it and am getting it saying the problem exits on time, loaded it up again, the problem doesn't exist (gpt data leftover or whatever is preventing me from dual booting)

I have found the developer of the program, on this site, and got his profile, is there an obvious way I'm missing to message him?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: NO.

Long answer: [copied shamelessly of Shog's answer in MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/213575):

---

Nope.

This has been suggested many, many times, going all the way back to the earliest days of the site. Prior to the creation of Meta SO, feature requests were posted on UserVoice:

- [Messaging between users](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/14640)

  > Declined without comment.
- [User messaging or wall](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/16805-user-messaging-or-wall)

  > it's possible we might have some kind of messaging function later, so as not to expose emails but let users communicate. But it's low priority.

*Comments were added to the system to allow users to communicate with each other **in the context of a specific post**.*

- [Allow private messages](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/99462-allow-private-messages)

  > it's about the questions and answers, not social networking. But if you want to contact someone, check their profile -- they will provide an URL or email address there.
- [How do you send a message to a stackoverflow user?](https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/216825-how-do-you-send-a-message-to-a-stackoverflow-user-)

  > Declined without comment

*Later on, the system was [expanded to allow notifying other users of comment-replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).*

Even with the ability to communicate with other involved users in regards to a specific post, the requests kept on coming. When Meta Stack Overflow replaced UserVoice, the number of feature-requests exploded:

- [Private message system unlocked by reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/how-user-messaging-could-be-realized)
- [Why don't we have instant messaging on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11635/instant-messaging-on-so-sf-su)
- [Is there a way to contact another member of stack overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18266/is-there-a-way-to-contact-another-member-of-stack-overflow)
- [Is there plans for an IM Capability?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18970/is-there-plans-for-an-im-capability)
- [Request a specific expert on a subject to answer your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41474/request-a-specific-expert-on-a-subject-to-answer-your-question)
- [Feature Request: "WAKE UP and accept my answer please"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50452/feature-request-wake-up-and-accept-my-answer-please)
- [My Social Network Integration for Private Messaging, Commenting, Etc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74952/my-social-network-integration-for-private-messaging-commenting-etc)
- [how can I get in touch with a stackoverflow member privately?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76420/how-can-i-get-in-touch-with-a-stackoverflow-member-privately)
- [Many, many more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22private+message%22)

The consistent response to this is that it's a bad idea, *because*:

1. It could hide information from the community: useful information transmitted privately is unavailable to other readers, subverting the core purpose of the site.
2. It could be used to harass other users ("Answer my question!", "Accept my answer!", "Yer momma so fat she overflows the stack!", etc...)

However, there is [some value](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/) in being able to communicate with other users outside the context of a specific question or answer. This point was conceded with the implementation of [a chat system](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/stack-overflow-chat-now-live/): users on every Stack Exchange site can create and participate in chat rooms, integrated with the normal user accounts. There are still no truly *private* messages between users, but for those who want to chew the fat or discuss *whatever* outside the confines of the sites themselves, this can provide a viable solution.

Finally, it became apparent that *moderators* occasionally need to contact users about sensitive topics, and relying on email for this created problems. [So the ability for moderators to send a private message to another user was implemented](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/moderator-messages/). The use of these messages are heavily restricted, reviewed by the system administrators, and reserved for critical messages *only*.

For normal users, the advice remains: if you *want* others to be able to contact you privately, add basic contact info to your profile's bio page.

Comment: so what do i do if i wanted to contact this person 
http://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith?

Comment: Email him? Check the link to his website.

Comment: @kris2340k **if you want others to be able to contact you privately, add basic contact info to your profile's bio page.** Is said in the answer.

Comment: Okay thank you, i will insure my profile is up to date with contect details and have his email from his website, Thanks guys

Comment: And don't e-mail people about posts or questions... I have gone so far as to take down links to my website due to messages that could easily be comments or chat. (And one users messages where reported as spam). Working on projects or other stuff out side the scope of the site is what e-mail is for.

Comment: @Mateo if you don't mention `@` the message don't reach him ;).